# How do I get all rows that contains a string in a field (SQL)?

Tags: sql, regex, content-management-system, metadata

I have a table called articles and I would like to retrieve all articles that contain a tag, in the `articleTags` field. The `articleTags` field contains a set of comma delimited strings (the tags).

If I am trying to find an article that contains the tag **php** from a table it should return results that had a articleTags field that looks like this -

- php
- c++,php,python

If I was doing this in PHP, I would simple use explode, but I don't want to go through every row in the database, and instead use a more efficient method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use the like operator

```
select * from articles where tag like '%php%'
```

if you are worried about tags which are not php but have php in them like say phphp then you can use with comma

```
select * from articles where tag like '%php,%' or tag like '%,php%'
```

Answer (score 1):

it match:

1. php
2. randomwordphp
3. phprandomword
4. randomphpword

Query

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE articleTags LIKE "%php%"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can use ["Oracle text"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/csql.htm#i997503)

And simply query data like

```
select * from articles where contains(fieldName, contentText) > 0
```

About Oracle text queries you can read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm)